# Remove specific leading zero's in pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to remove the specific number of leading zeros of one column in pyspark?

If you can see I just want to remove a zero where the leading zeros are only one.Then the output should be:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
|subcategory|output           |
+-----------+-----------------+
|      00EEE|            00EEE|
|    0000EEE|           000EEE|
|       0EEE|              EEE| 
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Similarly, If I want to remove from zero where leading zero is 2 then the output should be:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
|subcategory|output           |
+-----------+-----------------+
|      00EEE|              EEE|
|    0000EEE|           000EEE|
|       0EEE|             0EEE| 
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Is there any way?

Comment: how is "FFF" added ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a generic function to remove the leading "0" depending on the number you want:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def remove_lead_zero(col, n):
    """
    col: name of the column you want to modify
    n: number of leading 0 you want to remove
    """
    return F.when(
        F.regexp_extract(col, "^0{{{n}}}[^0]".format(n=n), 0) != "",
        F.expr("substring({col}, {n}, length({col}))".format(col=col, n=n+1))
    ).otherwise(F.col(col))


df.withColumn("output", remove_lead_zero("subcategory", 2)).show()
+-----------+-------+
|subcategory| output|
+-----------+-------+
|      00EEE|    EEE|
|    0000EEE|0000EEE|
|       0EEE|   0EEE|
+-----------+-------+

df.withColumn("output", remove_lead_zero("subcategory", 1)).show()
+-----------+-------+
|subcategory| output|
+-----------+-------+
|      00EEE|  00EEE|
|    0000EEE|0000EEE|
|       0EEE|    EEE|
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: what should be the value of n, if i want all the leading zeros to be removed?

Comment: @ArunMohan you do not use this solution to remove all the zeros